# Munin plugin in perl doesn't fetch correct data

Tags: perl, munin

I'm trying to use a Munin plugin for software raid. Here's the plugin's code: https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/disk/raid

Currently my raid is rebuilding, here's the current output:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      2925544767 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [==>..................]  resync = 14.4% (422554560/2925544767) finish=5246.6min speed=7950K/sec

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=DELAYED

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      4193268 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=DELAYED

unused devices: <none>
```

But when I run the plugin I get the following output (stating that all disks are synced):

```
# munin-run raid
md2.value 100
md2_rebuild.value 100
md1.value 100
md1_rebuild.value 100
md0.value 100
md0_rebuild.value 100
```

In the following lines I understand (I'm no programmer) that during the time the code runs, `$pct` is >= 100, and so `$rpct` gets set to 100 (which is my output for all raid arrays).
So which values do `$nact` and `$nmem` represent in my `cat /proc/mdstat` output? This would help me find out why $pct is >= 100.

```
my $pct = 100 * $nact / $nmem;
        my $rpct = 100;
        if ( $pct < 100 ) {
        my @output = `/sbin/mdadm -D /dev/$dev | grep Rebuild`;
        if( $output[0] =~ /([0-9]+)% complete/ ) {
            $rpct = $1;
        } else {
            $rpct = 0;
        }
```

I think this regexp holds the answer, but as I said, I'm no programmer :P

```
while ($text =~ /(md\d+)\s+:\s+active\s+(\(auto-read-only\)\s+|)(\w+)\s+(.*)\n.*\[(\d+)\/(\d+)]\s+\[(\w+)]/ ) {
    my($dev,$dummy,$type,$members,$nmem,$nact,$status) = ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7);
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
if ( $pct < 100 ) {
```

to this:

```
if ( $pct <= 100 ) {
```

and make sure you're running the plugin as root